# How does Silence work in the Sneak tree?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've leveled up my Sneak skill to 100 and attained Silence and assumed I would have little difficulty sneaking around unseen. However I can't tell any difference in the enemy detection rate and I still have gotten caught while trying to move away from a human enemy.
I've also seem to observed that beasts have a higher detection rate as well as Dragons.

I am asking this from a Lv.27 character with (100)Sneak, (5/5)Stealth and Silence.

Comment: Armor makes noise, too. Are you carrying heavy armor, or clinky parts? Hide armor won't make any extra noise, for example.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that I'm wearing Elven Armor (Light) with a Bow as a weapon.

Answer (score 20):

Silence removes all noise that your character makes from movement while in stealth mode. Effectively, this means that you must be seen (or smelled) to be detected. It is an almost entirely worthless ability, unfortunately, since the Muffle illusion spell (and the corresponding boots enchant) provide the exact same ability without wasting a perk.

While the Silence perk is a poor use of your limited points, the muffle effect is absolutely invaluable to a stealth-oriented character. Combined with the Invisibility illusion spell it allows complete undetectability to the vast majority of creature types, and it allows you to pickpocket and move around in close quarters far more easily than you could otherwise.

In general, stealth has been dramatically nerfed in Skyrim compared to previous Elder Scrolls games, and close attention to shadows and line-of-sight is now extremely important to avoid detection -- the old "sneaking in broad daylight" doesn't work now at any skill level with any amount of gear or perks.

From my personal experience, animals (and dragons) appear to have a significantly higher chance to penetrate stealth (and invisibility) than humanoids; presumably this is a "keen scent" ability of some kind.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. It seems I have indeed wasted a perk investing in Silence. It is linked to Shadow Warrior though and that sometimes comes in useful.

Now that you mention it, I do recall being in the moonlight while being spotted. It seems I will indeed pay more attention and stick to the shadows while sneaking next time.

Comment: @Jahuty its not a waste at all, becuse you need to pick silence to get the last perk in sneak, Shadow Warrior, that perk is kind of OP, you are in battle, just start to sneak and then you have 1 sec invis so you could sneak attack them for bonus damage
and then you could use that enchantment place you used for muffle for something else instead

Comment: Even then, Shadow Warrior is pointless with the Invisibility spell, and I feel that a Sneaky Character needs to be good at Illusions. After all, your arsenal is replete with trickery and deceit. Levelling Illusion is easy with the Muffle spell, and once you reach 100 in Enchanting, you can make a set of gear to reduce the cost of all Illusion magic to 0. Spam Muffle, and and follow the tree up though Animage, Kindred Mage, Quiet Casting, and Master of the Mind, and you will be able to go invisible in any situation., effectively saving you another perk point. In fact, with this setup, you only

Comment: "Even then, Shadow Warrior is pointless with the Invisibility spell" That is so wrong.... you can spam shadow warrior and attack over and over again with no time lag and take out a whole room with full X30 dagger attacks if you do it properly - invisibility takes some management to cast then attack then cast again ect.

Comment: If Silence equals Muffle, does this mean that we can save a Muffle enchant on boots and enchant something else, perhaps more stamina?  It might be worth the Stealth perk point if it means I can gain another enchant type!

Comment: WoW style min maxing has ruined a whole generation of video gamers. No dps meters in this game. Its an excellent perk depending on your playstyle. If you want to take the perk, take it. You'll level soon and get another one anyway.

Comment: I've made multiple stealth characters without a point in illusion who didn't even know the Invisibility spell. It works just fine, largely because Silence is awesome.